# querying dbpedia sparql for more results

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I want to obtain some data from dbpedia.
I have entities urls and want to get some information about localization.
Now i call query like this:

```
PREFIX geo: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

SELECT DISTINCT * WHERE 
{
  <{0}> rdfs:label ?label . 
    OPTIONAL {
     <{0}> geo:lat ?lat ;
     geo:long ?long .
    } .
    OPTIONAL {
     <{0}> dbo:Country ?dboCountry 
    } . 
    OPTIONAL {
     <{0}> dbpedia-owl:country ?dbpediaContry .
     ?dbpediaContry dbpprop:cctld ?ccTLD
    }. 
    OPTIONAL {
     <{0}> dbpprop:country  ?dbpropContry
    }
    FILTER ( lang(?label) = "en" )
}
```

for each url (replace {0} with url).
But I would like to optimize it and get result for more entities in one query.
Also is it possible to not set url in each line?

Regards
Piotr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, it looks I already have found an answer for both questions.
Do you know this(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)
Solution is:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT *

        WHERE {
            ?uri rdfs:label ?label .
            OPTIONAL { ?uri geo:lat ?lat .
                       ?uri geo:long ?long} .
  
        FILTER (?uri IN ({0}, {1}, ...)  )
        }
```

Maybe it will be helpful for somebody else?
Or maybe someone knows better solution?